# Components are not getting displayed while adding into CT presentation

Tags: content-manager

While trying to insert a Component Presentations in a Page, the window which opens after clicking 'insert' is not displaying Components or any other items?

Loading is not terminating as shown in the image. Please someone provide solution for this.

Comment: Have you performed regular database maintenance on the CM database, like updating statistics?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?  If the components have just been created, it could be that clearing the cache will show them for you.

Comment: Also check if there are script errors and try different browser

Comment: I am newly assigned as admin for tridion. Can you provide me a simple solution to fix this? @BartKoopman

Comment: I cleared cache and i restarted browser and checked. Its not working. Also components are not created recently.

Comment: start with reading the documentation on maintenance, and ask your DBA to maintain the database. If you are the DBA too, read up on proper database maintenance for high volume transactional databases.

Comment: Is the issue from browser side or server side? @BartKoopman

Comment: I can't answer that based on the little info you have given, but I ALWAYS first suspect the database to be the issue of performance problems like this, since 9 out of 10 times the database was not well maintained and updating the database statistics usually solves it.

Comment: You have two messages in the top-right corner. Could you click on the red square that says "2" at the moment and see if there are any helpful error messages in there?

Comment: If the browser was having issues connecting, you might see the errors steadily rise to "99+" as the client polls for updates from the Content Manager, but I'd still check for script errros in the browser. Is the problem specific to adding Component Presentations, though? The list views use the same approach and permission checks as far as I know, so might have the same problems in the main list view and navigation pane in the Content Manager Explorer.

Comment: And thanks for asking your first question here. The _solution_ is probably simple, but we need your help to first figure out what's the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your question contains a lot of unanswered variables, like what database you have (Oracle or MS SQL Server) and what type of system it is (dev or prod) and whether it is properly maintained or not and how old it is, is the issue only occuring on some clients or also directly on the server etc. etc. etc.

So I'll give you a very generic answer that should give you a nudge in the right direction:

1. if you just got assigned to be a SDL Tridion administrator, go to a sys admin training ASAP and learn about your new assignment. You can find details on the SDL website here http://help.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/web-content-management/sdltridion-sysadmins-dba.html
2. Read the documentation on maintenance of your system, that is your job now (assume it is never done, and it won't be done automatically unless you schedule something) http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-94283420-8A51-4F2C-913E-B18455E58D74
3. The documentation doesn't mention any specifics for MS SQL Server anymore, since that belongs in a standard MS SQL maintenance plan, but a trained DBA knows that there are some tasks he can better perform or schedule manually to keep DB performance up to par. You can read this old DB maintenance guide for some tips http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/MaintainingSDLTridiondatabases.aspx
4. `exec sp_updatestats` is a useful command for MS SQL Server, read up on that. It is the one command I would blindly run on a MS SQL Server Tridion DB and it has performed magical results (the longer it takes to run the first time, the more magic it will give you, as that shows how long it hasn't been run)
5. Truncating your transaction log on your database is the next best thing you can do. Especially for MS SQL Server, if it has never been truncated, chances are it is larger than 1GB which will bring the performance of your database to a standstill.
6. After you are sure the issue can't be caused by your database, i.e. you have performed and scheduled regular maintenance for it, then the next thing you should look into is possible issues on the CM server or the network to it. Is this only occuring for some clients, is it also occuring when the browser is opened on the server itself directly etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bala,

Try again with some other user login to the CMS. Sometimes it happened to me also. Or you clear your browser cache else clean up has to be done on the cms server.